# How to get a mongoose query to return only specific field inside of a document using Mongoose/ MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to code a menu manager where I can update delete and create both new menu items and categories. I need to get a query to return only the menu-items not all of the other category data inside of the document.

How can I do that?

This is the schema:

```
{
   Categories:
     name: ffjs,
     id: fhsjd,
     menu_items: [
       item1: {
         name: fhrse,
         ingredients: [jksf,sjdfk,fjd]
       }, ...
    ]
}
```

I would like the query to just return item1, item2, item3 and so on, but can't get the query to work.

I have tried:

```
Categories.find({"items" : $all})
Categories.find({}).select("items")
```

I've also tried querying for specific items just to test and only ever returns the full document such as :

```
Categories.find({"items.name" : "ramen"})
Categories.find({items :{"$elemMatch" : {name: "ramen"}}}, {"items.name" :1})
```

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried?

Comment: Just updated it for you:)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
You can use aggregate method to achieve it, check below:

```
Categories.aggregate([
    { $match: { $and: [{id: "fhsjd" }, { "items.name" : "ramen" } ] } },
    { $project: { _id: 0, menu_items: 1 } }
  ])
```

Here you can $match for query and $project for filter (0: to exclude and 1 to include)

**Solution 2:**
To return specific record, use below:

```
Categories.find({ "items.name" : "ramen" }, { items: 1, _id: 0 })
```

To return all items, use below:

```
Categories.find({}, { items: 1, _id: 0 })
```

Hope one of the solution works for you.

Comment: Check the link below for further understanding of Aggregate.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate